# Rails: instance variable not coming through in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments, actionmailer

I have a mailer `BetaInviteMailer` with action `beta_invite`, taking arguments `name` and `email` as follows:

```
class BetaInviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def beta_invite(name, email)
    mail to: email, subject: 'Invitation to my closed bèta'
    @name = name
  end
end
```

The `beta_invite.html.erb` reads:

```
Dear <%= @name %>,
...
```

When running `BetaInviteMailer.beta_invite("John Doe", "email@email.com")` in the console

The variable `@name` comes out 'nil'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you should first initialize the `@name` variable exactly before call the `mail(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BetaInviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def beta_invite(name, email)
    @name = name
    mail to: email, subject: 'Invitation to my closed bèta'   
  end
end
```

define @variable before mail call